# What is the meaning of @Priority for CDI @Interceptor?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-6

1) What is the meaning of @Priority for CDI @Interceptor ?

2) How does it relate to order of interceptors declared in beans.xml ?

3) Can @Priority be overwritten in xml file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Well, as the name suggests, it's meant to set priority (order) to the interceptors within Java EE application. Such interceptor will also be automatically registered so you don't have to define it in `beans.xml`.

2, 3) JBoss [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/interceptors.html#_enabling_interceptors) says that interceptors annotated with `@Priority` ale called before ones defined in `beans.xml`. Thus overwriting doesn't make any sense because order is already defined and you cannot turn off interceptors in `beans.xml` (you just can skip the declaration).