# Overwrite CDI configuration in xml file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-6

In jee (EJB, servlets) and many other java libraries (spring) there is a general rule that everything that is done via annotations can be overwritten with a xml file.

It seems to me that in case of CDI above rule doesn't apply. Please confirm or deny my opinion.

Does beans.xml accept only: alternatives decorators interceptors and scan top level elements (netbeans suggests only this)?

Can I for example create @Named CDI beans only via beans.xml file ?

Can I overwrite @Interceptor's @Priority in beans.xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I pointed out in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768424/what-is-the-meaning-of-priority-for-cdi-interceptor/33769578#33769578), you cannot overwrite interceptors in `beans.xml`. That's different from Spring where you can overwrite annotations by XML files or even merge them together. `beans.xml` is meant only for couple of following purposes (you can verify by looking at XSD [schema](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd))

- Defining interceptor classes
- Defining decorators
- Registering alternatives
- Conditional scanning

That's currently all you can do with CDI 1.1 `beans.xml`.